# Feature Selection in Mixture of Experts Model

Tags: feature-selection, latent-class, finite-mixture-model

I am just beginning to learn about Mixture of Experts Models, so I apologize if parts of my question are elementary.

My understanding is that a MEM is a mixture model where the components are linear regressions. So, in very informal terms, we iteratively calculate the probability (pi) of picking a given model i to predict y=f(X) (where X is a vector of features) AND the value of the parameters (held in vector theta)that minimize a cost function of the form:

C=E(pi*(y-theta*X)^2)... or one that accomplishes the same goal.

The idea is to make certain regression functions specialize on certain regions of the input space. EM method will bring us to local minima eventually and we're on our way to understanding the distribution of our dataset!

1) But, what happens if our feature space (vector X) is high dimension? That is, what do we do in situations where regularization would normally be used to bring down the number of features in our regression? Better yet, how do we select the feature space at all?

2) Are MEMs used for large p datasets in practice?

Thanks for any help you can provide (I would be very grateful for directions to articles that might help as well).